# Event Handling when option is selected from dropdown menu

Tags: html, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I have a form wherein I have to select an item from the drop down menu and display the selected value on the form. The values in the dropdown menu come from the database.
Here is my code of select:

```
<aui:select id="empName" name="empName" onChange = "showEmpName()">
<%
    List<Employee> EmpList =  EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployees(-1,-1);
    for(Employee emp : EmpList ) {
    %>
    <aui:option value='<%=emp.getEmpFname()%>' name = "leaveEmp" onClick =   "showEmpName()"><%=emp.getEmpFname()%>  <%=emp.getEmpLname()%></aui:option>

 <% } %>
```

Here is the script: the value selected from drop down should be displayed on the form

```
 <script>
function showEmpName()
{
    var empName = document.getElementById("empName")
    var showEmpName = document.getElementById("showEmpName")
    showEmpName.value = empName.value
    
    alert("my name is" + empName)
}
   </script>
```

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. `onchange` `onclick` aren't working.
2. Secondly I want to display the selected item on the form.

How should I approach?

EDIT:
I even tried the following but it doesn't work at all.

```
  <script>

    var selectedEmpName = document.getElementById('empName');
    var absentEmp = document.getElementById('absentEmp');
    
    selectedEmpName.onchange = function() {
        absentEmp.value = selectedEmpName.value;
    };
  </script>

                <aui:select id="empName" name="empName">
        <%
            List<Employee> EmpList = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployees(-1,-1);
            for(Employee emp : EmpList ) {
        %>
 <aui:option value='<%=emp.getEmpFname()%>' name = "leaveEmp"><%=emp.getEmpFname()%>      <%=emp.getEmpLname()%></aui:option>

<% } %>
    
  </aui:select>
```

The above code I am trying to display in a non editable text box.
What I actually want is once the value from drop down is selected it should be displayed as the value of the radio button which already exists. once the value of this radio button is set, it will be used for further processing.

EDITCODE:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#empName').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    $('label').text(value);
  });
});
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <portlet:actionURL name="markAbsent" var="markAbsentURL" />

<aui:form name="markAbsent" action="<%=markAbsentURL.toString() %>"    method="post" >


<aui:select id="empName" name="empName" >
        <%
            List<Employee> EmpList = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployees(-1,-1);
            for(Employee emp : EmpList ) {
        %>
  <aui:option value='<%=emp.getEmpFname()%>'><%=emp.getEmpFname()%>      <%=emp.getEmpLname()%></aui:option>

 <% } %>

    
 </aui:select>

  <label for="empName" id = "labelname"></label>
  </aui:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have the following html

```
<select id="mySel">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
  <option value="e">e</option>
  <option value="f">f</option>
</select>   
<label for="mySel">
</label>
```

And you use jQuery, then you should be able to listen to selections by

```
// attach a ready listener to the document
$(document).ready(function(){ // ran when the document is fully loaded
  // retrieve the jQuery wrapped dom object identified by the selector '#mySel'
  var sel = $('#mySel');
  // assign a change listener to it
  sel.change(function(){ //inside the listener
    // retrieve the value of the object firing the event (referenced by this)
    var value = $(this).val();
    // print it in the logs
    console.log(value); // crashes in IE, if console not open
    // make the text of all label elements be the value 
    $('label').text(value);
  }); // close the change listener
}); // close the ready listener
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/edamuh/3/edit

Or you could also do it with basic javascript, by putting the following *after* the generated select & label:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sel = document.getElementById('mySel');
  var lbl = document.getElementById('myLbl');
  sel.onchange = function(){
     lbl.innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  };
</script>
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/edamuh/7/edit

Note: The latter might not work equally in all browsers. 
Eg. Works in Firefox(Windows) but might not in others. Thus *I'd suggest opting for using **jQuery***.

**EDIT**

In your case the markup should be something like (no onChange):

```
<aui:select id="empName" name="empName" >
   <!-- options -->
</aui:select>
<label id="myUniqueLabelId"></label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    // assigns a listener to 1 or more select elements that contains empName in their id
    $('select[id*=empName]').change(function(){
      // when the change event fires, we take the value of the selected element(s)
      var value = $(this).val();
      // take an element with the exact id of "myUniqueLabelId" and make its text be value
      $('#myUniqueLabelId').text(value);
      // take the reference to a radio input
      var radio = $('#radioId');
      // make it enabled
      radio.prop('checked', true);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Working example with radio buttons:
http://jsbin.com/edamuh/12/edit

It is important to notice, that when the document loads the select must have been already rendered, otherwise the script won't work.

Comment: Thanks  a  lot Matyas but I do not understand why it isn't working. I tried both your approaches..
I mean it works as plain html file but when I try to include it in my code it doesn't display anything. I checked all the ids everything looks correct

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using but the handler on html elements should be placed on **onchange** and not *onChange*

Comment: I will try and see where I am making mistake and let you know

Comment: I have added my code as an EDITCODE above for your review since it still isn't working..

Comment: check that the ids in the rendered html are the ones that you reference in the jQuery script. Sometimes frameworks generate special ids. It might be that the id is markAbsent:empName (just a guess). + make sure that the label is unique in the page, or reference it through its id: $('#labelname').
It would be good to see the html output. maybe you can paste it somewhere and give a link here.

Comment: Here is the link http://pastebin.com/petMLcDT where I have pasted my html source.
I am using liferay framework

Comment: Matyas:
I was inspecting the generated code and the error says:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Comment: I am not sure about this but what I feel is that the value from the dropbox is not passed to the function . M just guessing , am not sure. But when I run the form and submit the data it gets successfully updated in my database. Also pls note that the dropbox is in my <form> tag. does it create a problem while passing it to javascript?

Comment: I generated the htmland I guess the erro that I mentioned in one of my previous comments lies in the follwing lines of code:
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/var empName=document.getElementById("empName");var emplabel=document.getElementById("emplabel");empName.onchange=function(){emplabel.innerHTML=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value};/*]]>*/

Comment: The jQuery doesn't work because the generated id is **_MallyaGroupMISPortal_WAR_MallyaGroupMISPortalportlet_empName**. So for the selector to work you have to use: `$('select[id*=empName]')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28097/discussion-between-matyas-and-cya-k)