# Event handler on chosen option

Tags: javascript

I need to handle alert event on chosen option.

```
  <select>
       <option value="1">A</option>
       <option value="2">B</option>
       <option value="3">C</option>
       <option value="3">D</option>
   </select>
```

For ex., if I choose "B" option, I want alert like "Chosen option is: B", etc...

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828485/get-the-option-value-in-select-in-javascript for a similar question.

Comment: there is no "alert event" in javascript - perhaps you want a `change` event on the `select` element

Comment: This post is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015933/javascript-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once Its Working .

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
   alert('You Selected'+' '+x);
}
```

```html
<p>Select a any value in list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">A
  <option value="2">B
  <option value="3">C
  <option value="4">D
</select>
```

Comment: `onchange="myFunction(this)"` using `function myFunction(sel) {
   alert('You Selected '+sel.value);
}` is simpler - you do need to add value="..." to your options too

Answer (score 0):

Working example: (It's a jQuery example, using selectors and events basically)

```js
// Wait for DOM load
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // Binding change event to the <select>
  $('#my_select').change(function() {
    
    // Saving the HTML corresponding to the value selected
    $selected = $('#my_select option:selected').text();;
    // Debugging actual selection DOM-node on console
    console.log($('#my_select option:selected'));
    // Showing the message
    alert("Chosen option is: " + $selected);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- I have set an ID to identify you select -->
<select id="my_select">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="3">C</option>
   <option value="3">D</option>
</select>
```

Some official jQuery's documentation links:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: The question was not tagged jQuery.

Comment: Also do not look for the select again: `var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();`

Comment: OK, working on that. My fault..

Comment: This has both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964561/event-handling-when-option-is-selected-from-dropdown-menu